# Run Python script persistently on server

Tags: python, ubuntu, telegram-bot

I have a python bot which I'm hosting on digital ocean. 
Right now to run it persistently I'm using virtual terminal screen and I see that this way is far from stable.

How I can schedule my bot script to run forever and being re-run if it crashes ? 
And also how I can schedule some other python scripts to run once in an hour ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Question 1. How to make things run forever.

There are a few ways to do this. You can create system service like systemd service ([tutorial here](https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6)), or you can use something like [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to do it. Both ways can help you restart on failure.

Lastly, you can still do it with either screen or tmux, but it won't be able to auto-restart on failure.

---

Question 2. How to run scripts periodically?

For this, there's a built-in program called `cron`. You can use it to automate triggering of any script, any time you specify.

[DigitalOcean: How to use cron to automate](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-cron-to-automate-tasks-ubuntu-1804)

tldr; you can just do `crontab -e` then add in the following

```
0 * * * * python /path/to/script.py
```

That will trigger the command on 0 minute of every hour of every day.

Here's a website which can be used to craft cron time format. https://crontab.guru/

Comment: Thank you for detailed instructions I will try them out soon and let you know!

Answer (score 1):

You can use crontab to schedule process.

To run hourly, you can use like this

- 0 * * * * /my/program/path

(minute, hour, day of month, month, day of week)